# Evaluate the improper integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Good evening, have problems with the next integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx$$
I tried to do it using Faymann's trick but it does not work out ... they could help me with the procedure or an idea

Making the change of variable with $x=\tan(y)$, what I got is,
$$\int\ln(\tan(y))dy=\int\ln(\sin(y))dy-\int\ln(\cos(y))dy$$

how can you continue?

Thank you

Comment: Try a change of variables $x = 1/u$. What do you get?

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160017/show-that-int-01-frac-ln1x1x2-mathrm-dx-frac-pi8-ln-2) integral is very similar to what you have here, probably some answer can help you.

Comment: Hi, how about, with the change of variable gives me the same integral, es decir, \[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(u)}{u^{2}+1}du\]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808678/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-ln-x1x2dx)

Answer (score 4):

Enforcing $x=1/u$ gives $dx=-\frac{1}{u^2}du$ and $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}} dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1/u)}{1+1/u^{2}}\frac{1}{u^2}du =-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx=-I$$

Hence $$ I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}} dx =0$$

Comment: Hi, how could you explain to me that I = 0, it is assumed that the change of variable and the derivative will be negative, and because of the logarithms, you have another negative and it becomes positive, that is, the whole integral it remains the same only with the letter u $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1)-\ln(u)}{\frac{u^{2}+1}{u^{2}}}\left(-\frac{1}{u^{2}}du\right)$$

Comment: @SantiagoSeeker apply the change of variable properly . zero becomes infinity vice versa and inverting the born of integration you recover the negative

Comment: Ahhh .... interesting ... Thank you very much!, Excuse one more question, Faymann's trick in what circumstances does it apply?

Comment: it is possible that the series doesnt converges, so the answer is correct whenever the integral converges

Comment: @Masacroso which series

Comment: sorry, I mean, the integral. Change "series" by "integral" in my previous comment

Comment: Excuse me, did someone delete the explanation of a user I was doing a moment ago using Faynman's trick? With series, the truth became long, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is trivially zero by symmetry, it is enough to enforce the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ on the interval $(1,+\infty)$. You may also notice that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\log(x)\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}$$
equals the opposite [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). Through [F**e**yman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman)'s trick,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^\alpha}{1+x^2}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1+\alpha} $$
leads to the very same conclusion by differentiating both sides with respect to $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx.$$
Under $x=\frac1u$, the second part of the above becomes
$$ \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}dx=-\int_{1}^{0}\frac{\ln(\frac1u)}{1+\frac{1}{u^{2}}}\frac{du}{u^2}=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(u)}{1+u^{2}}du$$
and hence
$$ I=0. $$